# how to send data to php webservice using GET method in JSON Format in C#

Tags: c#, php

I am new to webservice, and I am trying to send JSON data to .php webservice from my WP7 application created in VS2010. I have used the UploadStringAsync method, but this method is not working with the GET method. It is throwing exception while using the GET Method. Please help.

**below is my c# code**

```
WebClient postWithParamsClient = new WebClient();

postWithParamsClient.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";
postWithParamsClient.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(postWithParamsClient_UploadStringCompleted);

postWithParamsClient.UploadStringAsync(url, "POST", "{ \"latitude\": " + textBox2.Text.ToString() + ", \"longitude\": " + textBox3.Text.ToString() + " }");
```

**below is my webservice**

```
<?php
/*XML FORMAT
<gpstrack>
    <latitude>30°N</latitude>
    <longitude>38°N</longitude>
    <mobtime>mobiletime</mobtime>
</gpstrack>
XML FORMAT*/

$xml = file_get_contents('php://input');
$finalArray = json_decode(json_encode((array) simplexml_load_string($xml)),1);
//$finalArray=array('latitude'=>'12.1','longitude'=>'3.2','mobtime'=>'325695142');

$newfb = new TABLE($db,"gpslog","track_id");
$newfb -> latitude              = $finalArray['latitude'];
$newfb -> longitude             = $finalArray['longitude'];
$newfb -> mobtime               = strtotime($finalArray['mobtime']);

$newfb -> insert(); 
print "success";

exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

to use GET method, u'v to use `DownloadStringAsync` instead.